# Cannot set property of undefined - Modal Gallery- Possible scope issue?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to build a modal image gallery for myself and running into an issue where the div assigned to my modal is not being picked up by JS. My script tag is at the end of the file, I've defined the div to a variable. I'm thinking it might be a scope issue, but I'm very much a beginner:

```
var gallery = document.querySelectorAll('.modalImg');
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('#myModal');
var modalView = document.querySelectorAll('#img01');
var caption = document.querySelectorAll('#caption');

modalUp();

function modalUp(){
    for(var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {

        gallery[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalView.src = this.src;
            caption.innerHTML = this.alt;
        });
    };
};


<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img class="modalImg" src="1.jpg" alt="Fish">
        <img class="modalImg" src="2.jpg" alt="Vroom">
    </div>
    <!-- Empty Modal Box -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <img class="modalView" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></p>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="modaltest.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</html>
```

The error I get when I click one of my images: modaltest.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at HTMLImageElement. (modaltest.js:12)

I feel like I'm missing something basic here, but no other questions I could find quite correlated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modal` is a **collection** of elements (even though it contains only one element). Either use

```
var modal = document.querySelector("#myModal");
```

or use the age-old

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
```

to only find one element or access the first element of the collection as

```
modal[0]
```

Comment: Using `querySelectorAll` on an id selector is double-useless. Even if there was more than one element with that id, document.querySelectorAll would always only  return the first match.